# Remove default sample text in YUI Rich Text Editor

Tags: yui

Is there a way that the sample text inside the Rich Text Editor be removed?

Basically, I have a Rich Text Editor and has a "Sample Text Here" as a default value, I want the sample text be removed when I click on the editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Y.one('#some-button').on('click', function (e) {
    Y.one('#some-textarea').setHTML('');
});
```